# What is the name of this old glass pattern?

Tags: glass

We've accidentally managed to break the glass above our front door, by letting the door slam. I'd like to match the glass replacement, so it matches next door. I have no idea what the pattern is called, and don't know where to look to find a match.

We've had a glass fitter around to quote, who suggested that he had not seen this style and that it is likely not made any longer.

Does anyone know the name of the pattern or could possibly tell me of any good places / sites to look for old glass patterns?

[image: antique frosted glass]
[image]

Comment: It seems like modern styles come in a limited number of variations. I'm hoping that was the case with old styles otherwise the possibilities could be endless!

Comment: It's muranese very rare pattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this site](http://www.theglassguru.com/textured-glass.php) which lists many different styles of textured glass.

I think the particular one you had is somewhat close to the ***Florentine Wissmach*** on that site.

[image]

As for the best site to search, I'd say google image search, honestly. https://www.google.com/search?q=textured+glass+window&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: Thank you so much. That is the exact pattern. I had been looking under Google under 'frosted glass'. Seems that textured is a more appropriate keyword. Now to see where I can buy some!

Comment: And have now found a supplier for the replacement - note this is also known as 'Muranese' http://www.creativeglassguild.co.uk/prod/muranese-clear

Answer (score 7):

This glass pattern is "Muranese' and was first produced circa 1890.  Designed by the Glasgow Plate Glass Company (Murano St in Glasgow), later acquired by Chance Brothers of Birmingham.  Muranese was the most popular of all the Victorian 'fancy glass' designs and was produced by many companies around the world.  The pattern came in a small, medium and large variations and every tint possible.  1894 trade brochure.
[image]

Art glass suppliers offer similar reproduction patterns, often named Florentine.  Florentine was actually a similar pattern from the USA, dating back to circa 1895.  Whilst similar to Muranese, Florentine has a less dense floral cluster, with banding (parallel lines) incorporated.[image]

I have written several in-depth articles on Victorian & Edwardian glass. For more images of Muranese and florentine - https://sashwindowspecialist.com/blog/history-patterned-window-glass/

Comment: Mind disclosing your affiliation with the link (if you have one that is, if you aren't affiliated with it that's OK)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel "I have written" appears to be intended as disclosure of affiliation. While you're correct that it's not 100% clear, as the two sentences in the last paragraph are separate, I certainly took the first sentence as intending to indicate ownership of the blog.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer to the OP's question with all the above information except for the history lesson.

Comment: Yes I wrote the blog in the link, I am not trying to hide anything here.  Nor does the link try to sell you old glass, that's simply not the business we are in, This is an information only blog post that contains unique information that you wont find anywhere else.  Yes its a history lesson but some people value the extra information.